# Problema con navegacion usando MVVM en Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm, binding

Deseo navegar usando el patron MVVM en Xamarin.Forms, para ello bindo un comando a cierta imagen como se aprecia en la imagen...

[image: screenshot]

el codigo de esta vista esta bindado a la MainViewModel y a una propiedad llamada MenuSisquim ubicada dentro del StackLayout

MenuSisquimView.xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             BindingContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
              x:Class="AppValora.Views.Sisquim.MenuSisquimView">

    <ContentPage.Content>

        <StackLayout
          BindingContext="{Binding MenuSisquim}"
            HorizontalOptions="Start" 
            Margin="15">
            <Image Source="ic_sisquim_hds"
                   HeightRequest="130"
                   WidthRequest="130"
                   Margin="23,15">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                        Command="{Binding SelectHDSCommand}">
                    </TapGestureRecognizer>
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>

        </StackLayout>

    </ContentPage.Content> 
</ContentPage>
```

Esta propiedad MenuSisquim fue declarada en la MainViewModel de la siguiente manera:

```
public MenuSisquimViewModel MenuSisquim { get; set; }

    #region Constructor
     public MainViewModel()
     {
       instance = this;

       Login = new LoginViewModel();
       navigationService = new NavigationService();          
       LoadMenu();
      }
    #endregion

    #region Singleton
     static MainViewModel instance;

  public static MainViewModel GetInstance()
      {
      if (instance == null)
      {
        return new MainViewModel();
      }
      return instance;
      }
    #endregion
```

Entiendo que si estoy bindando el StackLayout a la Propiedad MenuSisquim, el comando que desplega el evento deberia estar implementado en mi MenuSisquimViewModel, la cual adjunto el codigo a continuacion

MenuSisquimViewModel.cs:

```
#region Servicios
public NavigationService navigationService { get; set; }
#endregion


#region Constructor
public MenuSisquimViewModel()
{            
    navigationService = new NavigationService();           
}
#endregion   

#region Comandos
public ICommand SelectHDSCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new RelayCommand(GoHDS);
    }
}

async void GoHDS()
{       
    await navigationService.NavigateOutMaster("FiltrosSisquimView");
}
#endregion
```

Es aca donde esta ocurriendo un problema!.. Cuando hago "Tap" no esta entrando en el comando! , ademas de no tener errores de compilacion, nose que esta ocurriendo! soy nuevo usando el patron MVVM y creo tener todo en orden, estoy usando un singleton para ver las instancias de otras ViewModels pero tampoco puedo ejecutar lo deseado...alguna ayuda para mi?

Comment: ¿en qué parte le asignas a la propiedad "MenuSisquim" un valor? Si usas un sistema de navegación en el ViewModel, ¿porqué no lo haces por medio de viewmodels y no de pasar nombres de vistas? para ese caso se me hace mas fácil que la navegación la hagas desde la vista.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba usar la interfaz de command en vez relaycommand

```
    public ICommand SelectHDSCommand
    {
        get { return new Command(GoHDS); }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Todo parece estar en orden pero no muestras todos los archivos relacionados con la funcionalidad MVVM.

Revisa este documento para que compruebes que no te falte algún paso antes de llegar a usar el comando.

https://1drv.ms/b/s!AnyHTwlYEmddgal4HE38yVx8ZXaPvw